# Timer not binding DOM value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, timer, countdown

I'm a backend developer, who's trying hard to make a timer by comparing two different date formats. This part of the script is working great, but whenever I try to make recursive call, nothing is binding.

I almost tried everything, from passing it into a function, using the $interval, the setInterval, and on and on. The main reason is I cannot get the value of its loop, and binding into my DOM.

Here is some of my code. Here I set all variables for the countDown() function.

```
   $scope.timer.list        = {};
    $scope.timer.date       = new Date();
    $scope.timer.list.D     = '00';
    $scope.timer.list.M     = '00';
    $scope.timer.list.Y     = '00';
    $scope.timer.list.h     = '00';
    $scope.timer.list.m     = '00';
    $scope.timer.list.s     = '00';
    $scope.begin            = {};
    $scope.begin.date       = {};
    $scope.begin.timer      = {};
    $scope.counter = {
        show : false,
        text : '00:00'
    };
    setInterval(function() {
        $scope.obj = {
            show : $scope.countDown($scope.privateshowcase.begin_at).show,
            text : $scope.countDown($scope.privateshowcase.begin_at).text
        }
        $scope.counter = $scope.obj;
    }, 1000);
```

Then, here is the function:

```
$scope.countDown = function(begin) {
    $scope.timer.date       = new Date();

    $scope.timer.list.D = $filter('date')($scope.timer.date, 'dd');
    $scope.timer.list.M = $filter('date')($scope.timer.date, 'MM');
    $scope.timer.list.Y = $filter('date')($scope.timer.date, 'yyyy');
    $scope.timer.list.h = $filter('date')($scope.timer.date, 'HH');
    $scope.timer.list.m = $filter('date')($scope.timer.date, 'mm');
    $scope.timer.list.s = $filter('date')($scope.timer.date, 'ss');

    $scope.begin.full = begin.split(" ");
    $scope.begin.date = $scope.begin.full[0].split("-");
    $scope.begin.timer = $scope.begin.full[1].split(":");

    $scope.begin.D = $scope.begin.date[2];
    $scope.begin.M = $scope.begin.date[1];
    $scope.begin.Y = $scope.begin.date[0];
    $scope.begin.h = $scope.begin.timer[0];
    $scope.begin.m = $scope.begin.timer[1];
    $scope.begin.s = $scope.begin.timer[2];

    if($scope.timer.list.Y == $scope.begin.Y) {
        if($scope.timer.list.M == $scope.begin.M) {
            if($scope.timer.list.D == $scope.begin.D) {
                $scope.counter.diff_h = $scope.timer.list.h - $scope.begin.h;
                if($scope.counter.diff_h == 0 || $scope.counter.diff_h == -1) {
                    if($scope.counter.diff_h == 0) {
                        if($scope.timer.list.m > $scope.begin.m) {
                            $scope.counter.show = false;
                            $scope.counter.text = false;
                        } else if ($scope.timer.list.m <= $scope.begin.m) {
                            $scope.counter.show = true;
                            $scope.counter.diff_m = $scope.begin.m - $scope.timer.list.m;
                            if($scope.counter.diff_m <= 30) {
                                $scope.counter.diff_s = 60 - $scope.timer.list.s;
                                if($scope.counter.diff_s == 60) {
                                    $scope.counter.s = "00";
                                    $scope.counter.diff_m_f = $scope.counter.diff_m + 1;
                                } else if($scope.counter.diff_s >= 1 && $scope.counter.diff_s <= 9) {
                                    $scope.counter.s = "0" + $scope.counter.diff_s;
                                    $scope.counter.diff_m_f = $scope.counter.diff_m;
                                } else {
                                    $scope.counter.s = $scope.counter.diff_s;
                                    $scope.counter.diff_m_f = $scope.counter.diff_m;
                                }
                                if($scope.counter.diff_m_f >= 1 && $scope.counter.diff_m_f <= 9) {
                                    $scope.counter.m = "0" + $scope.counter.diff_m_f;
                                } else {
                                    $scope.counter.m = $scope.counter.diff_m_f;
                                }
                            }
                            $scope.counter.text = $scope.counter.m + ":" +$scope.counter.s;

                        } else {
                            $scope.counter.show = false;
                            $scope.counter.text = false;
                        }
                    } else if ($scope.counter.diff_h == -1) {

                        $scope.counter.diff_timer = $scope.timer.m - 60;
                        $scope.counter.diff_m =  $scope.begin.m - $scope.counter.diff_timer;
                        if($scope.counter.diff_m > 30) {
                            $scope.counter.show = false;
                            $scope.counter.text = false; 
                        } else if($scope.counter.diff_m <= 30) {
                            $scope.counter.show = true;
                            $scope.counter.diff_timer_s = $scope.timer.s - 60;
                            if($scope.counter.diff_timer_s == 60) {
                                $scope.counter.s = "00";
                                $scope.counter.m = $scope.counter.diff_m + 1;
                            } else if($scope.counter.s >= 1 && $scope.counter.s <= 9) {
                                $scope.counter.s = "0" + $scope.counter.diff_timer_s;
                                $scope.counter.m = $scope.counter.diff_m;
                            } else {
                                $scope.counter.s = $scope.counter.diff_timer_s;
                                $scope.counter.m = $scope.counter.diff_m;
                            }
                            $scope.counter.text = $scope.counter.m + ":" +$scope.counter.s;
                        } else {
                            $scope.counter.show = false;
                            $scope.counter.text = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $scope.counter.show = false;
                        $scope.counter.text = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    $scope.counter.show = false;
                    $scope.counter.text = false;
                }
            } else {
                $scope.counter.show = false;
                $scope.counter.text = false;
            }
        } else {
                $scope.counter.show = false;
                $scope.counter.text = false;
        }
    } else {
        $scope.counter.show = false;
        $scope.counter.text = false;
    }
    return $scope.counter = {
        show : $scope.counter.show,
        text : $scope.counter.text
    };
}
```

'begin' is : 'YYYY/MM/DAY HH:MM:SS'

Maybe my way of thinking is not the good one, but at list I have a very functional timer, which replace every 1 to 9 into 01 to 09, convert the 60 into 00, can compare 2 different hours.

Comment: You say you're "trying hard to make a timer by comparing two different date formats." I don't quite understand, and your code isn't easy for me to grok. Can you explain a bit more about what your goal is?

Comment: It's a countDown, so the script is recovering a date from an API (begin: "'YYYY/MM/DAY HH:MM:SS') and then is compared to the current date return by the browser.

Comment: So you want it to display something like `10:00:00 remaining`, and then one second later update to `9:59:59 remaining`, and so on? Also, what format is `begin` in? Is it an integer of UTC seconds? Is it a human readable string?

Comment: Basically I'm returning 2 variables counter.show, and counter.text. Show is a  boolean, it triggers if the countDown div is showing or not. Text is the countDown() result which is something like '01:19' MM:SS. The function is working, and is doing nothing more than some basics math to get the correct value to display.

Comment: Exactly, and Begin is a basic NOW() SQL return, so it's a string like this 'YYYY/MM/DAY HH:MM:SS'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are over complicating things a little bit. I came up with a simple `countDown` component made in `angularjs 1.6.0` (it can be done with directives for angularjs older versions as well) that compares an input Date with the `now` Date.

You can play around with the input and change dates to see changes happen on the component, as long as you don't break the date format.

> **Note on dates:** simple way to compare dates:
>
> ```
> var date0 = new Date("2017-09-12T14:45:00.640Z");
> var date1 = new Date("2017-09-13T14:45:00.640Z");
>
> var dateDiff = new Date(date1.getTime() - date0.getTime());
> // "1970-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"
> ```
>
> Although `dateDiff` looks weird, it's basically one day from the zero date `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`.

Given that, you just let angularjs do the magic (or maybe trick).

```
{{ dateDiff | date:"d \'days\' hh:mm:ss" }}
```

> Besides, if you don't want to work with dates in the natural form of javascript, you can use [angularjs-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) which provide you date and time utility from [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) regardless of javascript dates pitfalls.

Here is the working code:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.countDownToDate = new Date().addDays(2);
  })
  .component('countDown', {
    template: '{{ $ctrl.timer | date:"d \'days\' hh:mm:ss" }}',
    bindings: {
      to: '<'
    },
    controller: function CountDownCtrl($interval) {
      var $this = this;

      this.$onInit = function() {
        $interval($this.setTime, 1000);
      };

      $this.setTime = function() {
        $this.timer = new Date(new Date($this.to).getTime() - new Date().getTime());
      }
    }
  });

// bootstrap the app
angular.element(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});

// extension to add days on date
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<div>
  <center>
    <h1>
      <count-down to="countDownToDate" />
    </h1>
    <label for="countDownToDate">To Date</label>
    <input type="datetime" name="countDownToDate" ng-model="countDownToDate">
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, I'm maybe over complicating, but I wanted to start the count down 30minutes before the beginning date, and things came out this way. I cannot change my date format, because it's an API response, and the owner dont want to change it.

Comment: It's ok, you can add minutes instead of days. Also, about the date format, you just have to parse it into a `Date` object like `new Date(2017,8,12,12, 11 + 30min, 00)`. Again, the component is dumb, it doesn't have to know about how you reach the date, just pass the date as an attribute (a.k.a., binding) and it's done.